# Exporting a Java project with external dependencies to a jar using Eclipse

Tags: java, jar

Is there an easy way to export a Java project including all of its external dependencies to a standard .jar file?

I have developed an SDK that uses several Apache libraries and I would like to be able to ship this project as a single jar. The answers I have found thus far to this question require the project to be packaged as a Runnable jar, and does not apply to this project which has no main class.

The rest of the answers I have found assume familiarity with Ant or Maven to accomplish this task, and I have no background with either. There are several scripts out there but I don't understand how I would use/modify them, or what I would to run the script and get a result.

Any answer that can provide more background into how exactly a user with no background with Ant or Maven would do these tasks is greatly appreciated.

For more background information I have trying to combine the following libraries into one called JetstreamSDK.jar

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-configuration-1.9.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
JetstreamSDK-Java.jar
jibx-bind.jar
jibx-extras.jar
jibx-run.jar
xpp3.jar
```

Comment: Typically, you just document your dependencies and rely on your library's consumers to ensure they are present on the classpath. Why do you feel the need to bundle specific artifacts along with your JAR?

Comment: I think, you can add a dummy Main class which will just print a message on how to use your SDK in `main()` method and then you can package it as a runnable jar from Eclipse. Consumers, can still use this library w/o relying on your main class.

Comment: @TomG I feel it is necessary to package the artifacts because this project is expected to have an extended lifespan. In my personal experience older libraries are often hard to find; and when newer version deprecate or remove functionality that the project uses the end user is out of luck. The SDK's purpose is to make things easier, and having the user search for libraries seems counter intuitive to that.

Comment: @JME The convention has shifted to relying on build tools such as Maven for transitive dependency resolution. In fact all the dependencies you have listed are present in the Maven Central repositories. However, if you don't want to tackle that learning curve, why not just offer a download of an archive containing all of the artifacts?

Comment: There are also disadvantages to the 'uber JAR' approach. Say I use your SDK, but I also need httpclient-5.0 down the road. Having both in my classpath can lead to class loading issues if yours appears first; I may not be able to load classes in the new version and I'll have to rebuild your SDK JAR to remove the old version.

Answer (score 1):

`jar` file is like `zip` compressed file. Usually Eclipse (default) java project will be organized like following directory structure:

```
some_project
       |____ src/ <--- your java source files
       |____ bin/ <--- compiled class files
       |____ lib/ <--- 3rd party libs e.g. commons*.jar
```

To package above structure and distribute as a single jar (zip) file- go inside `bin/` directory and select everything inside and just right click (assuming you are working on windows) and `send to` compressed (zipped) folder. Give a suitable name to the generated zip file e.g. `your-sdk.jar` then right click on `lib/` and compress into a another zip together with `your-sdk.jar` and you are done. This can be accomplished using `jar` command line tool also- but, you have to read the jar options/help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1.) First compile your project

2.) Right click on your PROJECT -> Export -> Java -> Runnable jar

3.) You will get a Dialog box, there select the class name (in which your main method resides)

4.) Give the export destination

5.) In library handling(radio button): select your desired option(all are self descriptive)

Comment: OP has already mentioned this option in his question (2nd para) but, he does not want to use as he does not have a Main class.